# Debug long running 'RELEASE SAVEPOINT <savepoint_name>'

Tags: postgresql

I have a savepoint which has been running for almost 24 hrs now. Its causing other issues like long running queries which refreshes materialized view concurrently.

Is there a way to know which query is causing the `RELEASE SAVEPOINT <savepoint-name>` to be in `idle in transaction`. Is it safe to use `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(__pid__);` against its pid?

Answer (score 0):

If the session is “idle in transaction”, it is *not* running.

What you see in `pg_stat_activity` is the last statement executed in that session.

There is a bug in your application that causes a transaction to remain open, and the locks that are held by this transmission can block concurrent sessions.